# MSI keyboard backlight

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I have tried to get my backlight on my MSI Steel Series keyboard to work. But I get an error message. Here is what I've done:

Install nodejs:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Install libusb:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0.0-dev
```

Create a folder, move in to it and create the following files:

package.json:

```
{ "name": "led-manager", "dependencies": { "msi-keyboard":"*" }}
```

server.js:

```
var keyboard = require('msi-keyboard');

keyboard.color('left', {color: 'red', intensity: 'high'});  
keyboard.color('middle', {color: 'green', intensity: 'high'});  
keyboard.color('right', {color: 'purple', intensity: 'high'});
```

Then I issue the following command:

```
sudo nodejs server.js
```

Which gives me this error:

```
/home/oscar/Skrivbord/Bla/node_modules/msi-keyboard/lib/setColor.js:24
    keyboard.sendFeatureReport(activate);
             ^

Error: could not send feature report to device
    at Error (native)
    at module.exports (/home/oscar/Skrivbord/Bla/node_modules/msi-keyboard/lib/setColor.js:24:11)
    at HID.board.color (/home/oscar/Skrivbord/Bla/node_modules/msi-keyboard/lib/findKeyboard.js:12:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/oscar/Skrivbord/Bla/server.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
```

How do I get the backlight to work properly? I couldn't find any answers on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! It was not very easy. First don't install the newer versions of node, use the one in the ubuntu repo (v0.10.25 as of writing). This version of node doesn't contain npm so you have to install it aswell. Also  make sure you have libusb-1.0.0-dev installed.

Create a directory to store your files. I will use `~/keybaord`.

The installation of msi-keyboard needs the node executable to be called node and not nodejs, so we start by making a temporary symbolic link and add that to our PATH:

```
ln -s `which nodejs` ~/keyboard/node
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/keyboard
```

Now we can install msi-keyboard (make sure you are in the directory you want to install it to):

```
npm install msi-keyboard
```

Now you can delete the temporary symbolic link and create a file yourfile.js with your script that controlls the keyboard. Run it with

```
sudo nodejs yourscript.js
```

Comment: *sigh* so until this is fixed for node 4.x and higher, if you actually need newer node for work, you are boned. nice. Good job on the work-a-round though :)

Comment: Yes, it would be great if they made it work with newer versions of node. What you can do is install the nave package through npm in any version of node to install older versions of node. I use 0.12.6 to control the backlight and it works perfectly.

Comment: I have to back peddle slightly here - after pulling the latest source from msi-keyboard project, re-running `npm install`,  things actually started working. This is using node 4.4. So...seems to be fixed at least for that version.

Comment: Really? Those are great news! I have to try sometime. How did you pull the latest source? Does npm do it automatically?

Comment: no unfortunately not via NPM. I cloned the [git repo](https://github.com/stevelacy/msi-keyboard), then ran `npm install`. It builds and then installs in local npm cache, from there you can use in other project